# Create `/gazebo` node with namespace

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-11, namespace, ros-foxy, gazebo-ros

I'm using ROS2 foxy, gazebo 11. I got `/gazebo` ros node after running `gazebo_ros` launch file

```bash
$ ros2 launch gazebo_ros gzserver.launch.py
```

, and

```bash
$ ros2 node list
/gazebo
```

I need multiple `/gazebo` node with different namespaces, e.g. `/<ns_1>/gazebo`, `/<ns_2>/gazebo` ...

> I'm not familiar with Gazebo Plugins, and I found that in `gzserver.launch.py`, they used `libgazebo_ros_factory.so` plugin, that may create the `/gazebo` node

Could you please provide any suggestion for meet the requirement?

Thanks